# Keeping domain same after nginx forwarding?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a setup that is presented below:

domain_name -> nginx_ip_address -> wordpress_blog_ip_address

Where when a user visits "/blog", nginx forwards the request to a seperate ip address of a machine running a wordpress blog.

The problem is that when the user clicks on a post in the blog, the url will show as: "wordpress_blog_ip_address/post" and not "domain_name/blog/post". How can I fix this?

My current nginx file is below:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /blog {
    proxy_pass http://new_ip_address/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that wordpress is configured to use `wordpress_blog_ip_address/` as a absolute url, and all url wordpress return will start with `wordpress_blog_ip_address/`. To change this absolute url, in `wp-config.php`, set `WP_SITEURL` to be dynamically generated, i.e.:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' );
```

and the same for `WP_HOME`, `WP_CONTENT_URL`, `WP_PLUGIN_URL` and other field containing absolute url. ( use search feature in your editor. )

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by forcing Wordpress to output relative URL by using [Relative URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/) plugin.